# Unity "pacman effect" on UI element

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

In Unity using C#, how do I make an UI element "teleport" to the other side of the screen when reaches the border but not all together?

I have an aiming circle that moves freely in the screen like in the old "on rails" shooters, but when it reaches an end of the screen it should "teleport" slowly and ot suddenly to the other side (i.e. if the circle is 1/3 out of the screen, only 1/3 should go to the other side).
[image: Like this]

Thanks a lot to anyone who can help!

Comment: Why not simply use two Image components?

Answer (score 3):

Have two entities that are nearly identical spaced exactly 1 screens width apart and move together.

Comment: Well, three. One left, one right, one center. When the center one finally leaves the screen, that's when you teleport it.

Comment: Or just teleport the one from left to right and vice versa as the center one crosses the center line of the screen. If you need to do this vertically as well, you would need to track 4 identical elements though, one for each corner of the screen.

Comment: Oh nice, didn't think of that, thank you! And to shoot how would you signal which is the "right one"? The one which center is in the screen right?

Comment: If you have to choose just one of them to fire with, then choose whichever one is more on the screen. If they are exactly equal, then make the equation biased towards one over the other. i.e. (assuming center of aiming circle is x, y, and screen dimensions are w, h) when pressing shoot, the area under the aim is shot if that aim's x >= 0 and x < w. If the aim circles are exactly w distance apart, only one of them will ever shoot.